# I'm using WebStorm for node.js development but the core modules are not in the JS library

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I'm trying to *require* modules such as `http` and `fs` but these module are missing. Actually, `require()` itself is not recognized by my WebStorm.

What's causing this? How can I get the core modules?

Attached is a screenshot of my JavaScript libraries:

[image]

P.S. My software is 100% legit (I have a valid license etc.)

Comment: This is not a question for StackOverflow, more something for SuperUser. However, you might try installing plugins. However, [according to the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/node-js.html) the latest Webstorm already supports Node.JS out of the box. (Try the "Before you start" chapter)

Comment: here's the problem: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000273064-I-don-t-have-the-core-modules-in-my-JS-libraries?page=1#community_comment_115000266270

Comment: *"P.S. My software is 100% legit (I have a valid license etc.)"* That's absolutely irrelevant here -- IDE functionality does not depend on that, at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure to enable **Node.js Core** library in ёSettings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPMё:

[image]